# Can't get the exit statement to print and the else to print which is for any input that does not match a menuOption

Tags: java, machine-learning, project, shapes

I simply could not get the last two statements to print

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class Practice {
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

I had a login for the machine here and it works so I just deleted that part. Other than that it just seems to be an error with the loop I have created. I just need some help with understanding where I went wrong.

```
                //Body of Shape Machine

                String menuOption = "";


        while(!(menuOption.equals("Exit"))){
                String circles = ("Circles");
                String rectangles = ("Rectangles");
                String triangles = ("Triangles");
                String exit = ("Exit");

                System.out.println("---Welcome to the Shape Machine---");
                System.out.println("Available Options:");
                System.out.println(circles);
                System.out.println(rectangles);
                System.out.println(triangles);
                System.out.println(exit);
                System.out.println("");

                menuOption = input.next();      

    if (menuOption.equals("Circles")){  

                //CIRCLES
                System.out.println("Circles selected. Please enter the radius:");
                double userRadius = input.nextDouble();

            if (userRadius < 0) {
                while (userRadius < 0){
                System.out.println("#ERROR Negative input. Please input the radius again:");
                userRadius = input.nextDouble();
                }
            }

                input.nextLine();

                if (userRadius > 0){
                    double circumference = (2 * userRadius * Math.PI);
                    double circleArea = Math.PI * userRadius * userRadius;
                    System.out.println("The circumference is: " + circumference);
                    System.out.println("The area is: " + circleArea);

                String digitsCircumference = Double.toString(circumference);
                String digitsCircleArea = Double.toString(circleArea);

                    System.out.println("Total number of digits in the circumference is: " + (digitsCircumference.length()-1));
                    System.out.println("Total number of digits in the area is: " + (digitsCircleArea.length()-1));
            }
            continue;
            }   

    if (menuOption.equals(rectangles)){

                    //RECTANGLES

                    System.out.print("Rectangles selected. Please enter the 2 sides: ");
                    double rectangleSide1 = input.nextDouble();
                    double rectangleSide2 = input.nextDouble();

            while (rectangleSide1 < 0 || rectangleSide2 < 0){
                    System.out.print("#ERROR Negative input. Please input the 2 sides again: ");
                    rectangleSide1 = input.nextDouble();
                    rectangleSide2 = input.nextDouble();

                }           
                    double rectangleArea = (rectangleSide1 * rectangleSide2);
                    double rectanglePerimeter = ((rectangleSide1 * 2) + (rectangleSide2 * 2));
                    System.out.println("The area is: " + rectangleArea);
                    System.out.println("The perimeter is: " + rectanglePerimeter);
                    String digitsRectangleArea = Double.toString(rectangleArea);
                    String digitsRectanglePerimeter = Double.toString(rectanglePerimeter);
                    System.out.println("Total number of digits in the area is: " + (digitsRectangleArea.length()-1));
                    System.out.println("Total number of digits in the perimeter is: " + (digitsRectanglePerimeter.length()-1));
                    continue;
                }


    if (menuOption.equals("Triangles")){

                    //TRIANGLES

                    System.out.print("Triangles selected. Please enter the 3 sides: ");
                    double triangleSide1 = input.nextDouble();
                    double triangleSide2 = input.nextDouble();
                    double triangleSide3 = input.nextDouble();
            while (triangleSide1 < 0 || triangleSide2 < 0 || triangleSide3 < 0){
                    System.out.print("#ERROR Negative input. Please input the 3 sides again: ");

                    triangleSide1 = input.nextDouble();
                    triangleSide2 = input.nextDouble();
                    triangleSide3 = input.nextDouble();
            }
            if ((triangleSide1 + triangleSide2) <= triangleSide3 || (triangleSide1 + triangleSide3) <= triangleSide3 || (triangleSide2 + triangleSide3) <= triangleSide1){
                    System.out.println("#ERROR Triangle is not valid. Returning to menu.");
                    continue;
            }
            if ((triangleSide1 + triangleSide2) > triangleSide3 && (triangleSide1 + triangleSide3) > triangleSide3 && (triangleSide2 + triangleSide3) > triangleSide1){

                double trianglePreliminary = (triangleSide1 + triangleSide2 + triangleSide3)/2;
                double triangleArea = Math.sqrt(trianglePreliminary * ((trianglePreliminary - triangleSide1) * (trianglePreliminary - triangleSide2) * (trianglePreliminary - triangleSide3)));
                double trianglePerimeter = (triangleSide1 + triangleSide2 + triangleSide3);

                if ((triangleSide1 == triangleSide2) && (triangleSide2 == triangleSide3)){
                    System.out.println("The triangle is: Equilateral");
                }               
                else if ((triangleSide1 == triangleSide2) || (triangleSide2 == triangleSide3) || (triangleSide1 == triangleSide3)){
                    System.out.println("The triangle is: Isosceles");
                }
                else if ((triangleSide1 != triangleSide2) && (triangleSide2 != triangleSide3) && (triangleSide1 != triangleSide3)){
                    System.out.println("The triangle is: Scalene");
                }

                System.out.println("The perimeter is: " + trianglePerimeter);
                System.out.println("The area is: " + triangleArea);
                String digitsTrianglePerimeter = Double.toString(trianglePerimeter);
                String digitsTriangleArea = Double.toString(triangleArea);
                System.out.println("Total number of digits in the area is: " + (digitsTrianglePerimeter.length()-1));
                System.out.println("Total number of digits in the perimeter is: " + (digitsTriangleArea.length()-1));
                continue;
            }

 here I have trouble and I can not get these menuOption statements to print. I am not sure why either.

        if (!(menuOption.equals("Exit")))
            {
            System.out.print("Terminating the program. Have a nice day!\n");
            System.exit(0);
            }


        else 
            {   
            System.out.print("#ERROR Invalid option. Please try again.\n");
            continue;
            }
        }                       
    }   
}
```

Comment: hint: read about "clean code" and the single layer of abstraction principle. You really really do not want to stuff so much code into that single poor method! Doing so would make your code easier to read, maybe so easy to read that even you would find the bug in your own code; instead of relying on dumping this (sorry) mess on other people.

Answer (score 1):

Remove !(not) operator from the following condition

```
 if (!(menuOption.equals("Exit")))
```

Comment: You don't need the backticks if you have the four whitespaces in front of your code.

Answer (score 0):

## Java is OOP

Java is designed for Object-Oriented-Programming so you probably want to use different classes and a type hierarchy... But this probably overkill for something like this.

> So use Scriptlanguages for this like Python, Powershell ...

## If you want to stick at this Java style

At least use different functions. One for circles one for rectangles and so on.

```
public static double circleArea(double radius){
  return Math.PI*radius*radius;
}
//for circumference, rectangle area...
public static void processCircle(){
  System.out.println("You selected Circle");
  double radius = inputDouble("Radius:",x->{return x>=0});
  System.out.println("Area: "+circleArea(radius));
}
```

You probably wondering about `inputDouble("Radius: ",x->{return x>=0})`. This is from my next tipp. Do not repeat code! You often take input and test whether it is valid. The `inputDouble` function is defined as it follows:

```
public static Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
public static double inputDouble(String popup, Function<boolean> condition){
  double out;
  while(!condition.applyAsDouble(out=scanner.nextDouble())){
  }
  return out;
}
```

In your main function you have the variables `exit`, `rectangles`, `triangles` but you don't use them in your if statements. You also might use case-insensitive comparison

```
if(menuoption.equalsIgnoreCase(circles)){
  processCircle();
}
```

So now to your actual question. I think I probably did a little bit too much. :)
You have

```
if(!menuoption.equals("Exit")) {
```

but you want

```
if(menuoption.equalsIgnoreCase(exit)) {
```